# rspec MissingTemplate error on :format => :json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, rendering

Im using rspec and factory_girl on my tests. The issue comes when i intend to test a method rendering json response.

My appointments_controller method:

```
def index
  @appointments = @user.admin ? @company.appointments : @user.appointments
end
```

Im not setting the format here because i only call this method like "appointments.json". I specify that on my test using :format => :json.

appointments_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all appointments as @appointments" do
    appointment = FactoryGirl.create(:appointment)
    get :index, { :company_id => user.company.to_param, :user_id => user.to_param }, :format => :json
    expect(assigns(:appointments)).to eq(Appointment.all)
  end
end
```

The problem is, as you might see in the stack here, it still looks for an html response:

```
Failure/Error: get :index, { :company_id => user.company.to_param, :user_id => user.to_param }, :format => :json
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template appointments/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
respond_with(@appointments)
```

after settings the @appointments

```
respond_to :json
```

in the beginning of controller.

**Update**

How about specifying it like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @appointments.to_json }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @sanfor. Now is ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Comment: Still UnknownFormat. I'll take your answer as correct anyway because it did solve MissingTemplete error